# GIT Branch - Check if branch is locked, without trying to push

Tags: git, github, github-api

My question is simple:

**How can i check if GIT branch (of some repo) is locked, without trying to PUSH to that branch?**

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "locked"?

Comment: Git does not have branch locking. Git *Hub* has *protected* branches, but there is no way to find out about them from Git, only from GitHub.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#get-branch-protection

Comment: This is the deal,
Lets say i have 5 repos, each repo has 10 branches.
Some branches are "restricted" means no one except for Admin can push into them.

Is there a way to know that there was a restriction set?
@phd, I will have a look into that.

Its jus that we have few GIT hosting systems (TFS,GitCommit,GitHub), each system has its own way of maanaging the Security and restrictions.

Ty for now guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git has no intrinsic concept of branch locking or protected branches.  Git can attempt to push to a branch, and that operation can either succeed or fail, possibly with an error message.  However, there's no way of querying with Git whether an operation would succeed since in many cases the operation is dependent on the data pushed.  Git doesn't provide a dry-run mechanism in the push API, since uploading a large amount of data just to throw it away would be slow and wasteful.

If you want to know whether a branch is protected, you'd have to use the API of your particular hosting service to see whether it's protected.  If you have multiple hosting services, then you'll probably need to write a script that abstracts over them.

For GitHub, the [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#get-branch-protection) covers the branch protection options.

Comment: I was kinda hoping that there is a way.
Either way, thanks for the thorough explanation.